# Best workaround for volunteer database with training journals

Tags: civicase, civivolunteer, civihr

I’m hoping to create a volunteer section that will record and report on personal details, work location and training courses status etc. It was suggested that CiviCase would be the best option, creating each course as a case?

Comment: I would be surprised if using each Course as a Case is the way to go.

Comment: You may be able to do most of what you need just with Custom Fields and perhaps some Custom Activity Types - eg if you need to track that folk keep their certificates up to date. May help others help you if you spell out more details.

Comment: I agree CiviCase may be a bit OTT and CiviEvent, custom activity types and custom data may be all that's needed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Civi Event + [civivolunteer](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civivolunteer) extension?

Comment: Civivolunteer is basically broken out of the box at this point. It's theoretically possible to make it work by doing a bunch of manual database upgrades if you dig through the upgrade code, but it is non-functional if you install it fresh and try to use it.